# Caml query returning extra divs

Tags: development, caml

I need my caml query to return only text, e.g. now it's returning me this

```
<div class=ExternalClass104BBsdfEEDCEdddsf48C68C18AsdfB056FBsdfAB805>Real Content.....</div>
```

When I want `Real Content.....` only. Code I am using is can be found here

http://snahta.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/discussion-board-multiple-item-threaded.html

Problem is in above example they are getting list items into a data table so i can't use this statement,

```
item.Fields["Body"].GetFieldValueAsText(item["Body"]).ToString().Trim();
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the type of your column?

Comment: it's type is banana, it's body column of discussion list

Comment: What is the type???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAML isn't going to strip out that div as it's part of the column data. You are going to need to use a regex to strip that out after the data has been retrieved.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/180312